# Is it correct to use 'reimagine' to describe something that has already happened?

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context

A freelancer who is a native speaker wrote the sentence. I don't understand the use of 'reimagined'. The open walkway is already a reality. Is it correct to use 'reimagine' to describe something that has already happened?

> Upon entering the library, the central area, which was once occupied
> by tables and chairs, has now been **reimagined** as an open walkway.

[image]

Comment: In this context, it means "redesign" or imagine a new interior layout .

Comment: It looks fairly silly to me. Someone trying to impress with fancy vocabulary.  But interior designers to sometimes talk like this.

Comment: @JamesK Agreed, and worst it may mean "redesigned", many would deduce that something imagined didn't actually exist or take place whilst, in reality, it obviously has.

Comment: @JamesK - Some people seem to think (I have seen pieces in e.g. the _Atlantic_) that Western culture is maybe running out of new ideas and every god-damned thing has to be reimagined, reinterpreted, done over, warmed over, regurgitated, recycled, etc (use of approving or pejorative terms depending on how you feel about that, or whether the action is expected to pay your wages). _Richard III_ reimagined as a rap musical. Wagner on roller skates. A deconstructed cheeseburger for £50. Etc.

Comment: @JamesK - It's in Cambridge, so I don't think it's totally silly, but possibly a bit grand for a library layout. Perhaps a 'freelancer' imagines that fancy words justify their fee. A 2006 draft entry to the OED gives an example from 1868 _The psyche being the more sensational agent, it will, no doubt, be proved that this ‘principle of being’ was the precursor and originator of this organised matter:—as Aristotle speculated and Stahl reimagined._

Comment: Hello everybody, the freelancer rewrote it and now uses 'function':  the central area, previously occupied by seating, now **functions** as an open pathway.

Comment: You're just asking us to double check what your 'freelancer' provided. I believe that's proofreading, and requests for that are off-topic.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, I'm not. I am just saying that he offered a solution. I know 'function' is a good word choice here.

Comment: Is the freelancer paid by the word?

Comment: _Wagner on roller skates._ - The Glide of the Valkyries - title and idea © 2023 by Michael Harvey. Applications for licensing deals may be made here.

Comment: I ask if the freelancer is being paid by the word, because I think this is a better rewrite: the central area, previously occupied by seating, is now an open pathway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the word "reimagine" literally means to *imagine* something differently, it's mostly used to describe *a change that is already done*.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reimagine) has this to say:

> **:** to imagine again or anew
> especially **:** to form a new conception of **:** ***re-create***

In your context, "reimagined" means re-created. The area used to have tables and chairs, but someone had the idea to remove those and make it an open walkway, and now that's what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The library staff have decided to change the use of the central area, and have now completed that action. This is a normal usage.

> reimagine
>
> verb
>
> to have a new idea about the way something should be

[Reimagine (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reimagine)